# google visualization get chart as an image (java)

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

Using Google Visualization api in Java I have created a PieChart:

```
PieChart chart = new PieChart(data, options);
```

I now want to save the chart as an image.  Is there a way to export this chart to an image?

Answer (score 0):

google charts have a [`getImageURI`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) method

which returns a base64 string, that can be saved as a `PNG`